# How to get assembly version via vbs

Tags: windows, dll, vbscript, version

I don't talk about file version that I can get by following script:

```
Set args = WScript.Arguments
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
WScript.Echo fso.GetFileVersion("somedll.dll")
Wscript.Quit
```

How can I get version of dll that is visible e.g. in GAC?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use `gacutil` to search for your assembly and write the output to a text file that you could then parse.

For example:

```
Const GACUTIL_PATH  = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\gacutil.exe"
Const ASSEMBLY_NAME = "System.Web.Mobile"
Const TEMP_FILE     = "c:\out.txt"

' Run the gacutil.exe utility....
With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    .Run Chr(34) & GACUTIL_PATH & Chr(34) & " /nologo /l " & ASSEMBLY_NAME & " >" & TEMP_FILE, 0, True
End With

' Read the output file...
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    strOutput = .OpenTextFile(TEMP_FILE).ReadAll()
End With

' Find the "Version" attribute...
With New RegExp
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "Version=(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+),"
    Set Matches = .Execute(strOutput)
End With

' Display each version in the GAC...
For Each Match In Matches
    MsgBox Match.SubMatches(0)
Next
```